# Automated Unity iOS build on Mac

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am doing the iOS builds for a group of Unity (Unity3d) game developers.

After pulling the latest git updates, I start up the Unity editor on my Mac and choose "Build Settings", select the iOS target platform, press Build, specify a destination folder and that is it.

Can this exact process be done automatically via the terminal prompt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you would need to do is create an editor method in Unity that does the iOS building:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer.html

And then call that method via the Unity command line arguments.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

```
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -executeMethod MyEditorScript.MyMethod
```

Answer (score 1):

As Calvin said, you can use the executeMethod switch of Unity's [command line](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) to call your own C# command and have some build logic executed. I have written a small [article about how to do this](https://effectiveunity.com/articles/making-most-of-unitys-command-line.html). There is also a [cheat sheet](https://effectiveunity.com/articles/unity-editor-automation-cheat-sheet.html) showing the Unity API to use for specific tasks.

Comment: Looks like the link to the [article](https://effectiveunity.com/articles/making-most-of-unitys-command-line.html) is broken.